# WCF: Closing channel leaves stream open

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I get a Stream from a WCF-Service. I am using this stream to get data from it and copy it to another stream.

```
IServerService serverService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
Stream serverStream = serverService.GetStream();
serverStream.CopyTo(localStream);
```

That works fine.

Now I have a scenario where I need to break up the process on some interrupt. I tried to call
`channelFactory.Close()` and `channelFactory.Abort()` to stop the copy. But it does not work. The Server-Stream still copies data to the Local-Stream.

I would like to know why this does not work, and how I can force close the stream.
(I know that I can close the Server-Stream to stop it, but I would like to close the ChannelFactory or the Channel)

Also is it possible to close the ChannelFactory so it closes all channels and streams immediately?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't unless you are using an asynchronous call. Refer to this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/277137a7-a349-4dfa-89a9-6d50427d37c7/wcf-streamedresponse-how-to-abortinterrupt-reply-stream?forum=wcf

Comment: I will close the stream and run into a exception. Thanks.